# The folder not found in directory on reboot

Tags: 12.10

I created a folder in 'tmp' directory in root and saved some downloaded material in it. After reboot I am unable to find it in 'tmp' though searching through Dash Home shows the folder location in 'tmp'. Tried 'locate' and 'find' commands to locate the folder but unable to locate it. Even ctrl+H in 'tmp' does not show the folder. Plz help how to locate it even if it has moved to some other directory. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

tmp is a directory used by the system itself for temporary files. It is emptied every time you shut down the computer. So I suggest using some program for recovering files. Perhaps PhotoRec will work.